# Не получается отправить POST запрос

Tags: php, post, api

Пытаюсь подключиться к API LEADS.SU и отправить анкету.

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init("http://api.leads.su/webmaster/leads/push?");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(

            "token"             =>  "58803b7d540dd0304d3b6c9101665222",
            "platform_id"       =>  "1082221",
            "offer_id"          =>  "485",
            "birthdate"         =>  "1978-12-01",
            "birthplace"        =>  "Воронеж",
            "credit_days"       =>  "20",
            "credit_sum"        =>  "5000",
            "fact_city_name"    =>  "Воронежская область",
            "fact_region_name"  =>  "Воронеж",
            "firstname "        =>  "Сергей",
            "gender"            =>  "male",
            "lastname"          =>  "Иванов",
            "middlename"        =>  "Анатольевич",
            "mphone"            =>  "79507747250",
            "overdue_loans"     =>  "credit_closed_no_delay",
            "passport_code"     =>  "2010555698",
            "passport_date"     =>  "1999-06-01",
            "passport_title"    =>  "123-001 Пролетарским РОВД",
            "reg_city_name"     =>  "Воронежская область",
            "reg_region_name"   =>  "Воронеж",
            "is_test"           =>  "1"

        ));
        $body = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Но ничего не получается. Нет ошибок, но в истории конверсий анкеты тоже нет. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

попробуйте исправить на

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Comment: увы, не сработало(

Comment: у меня выдает ошибку "Access token is missing". Правильно ли вы используете API?

Comment: token 58803b7d540dd0304d3b6c9101665c23 и "platform_id"  => "1088801"

Comment: а есть возможность посмотреть как работает их API?

Comment: http://webmaster.leads.su/tools/api , но потребуется рега

Comment: Со вторыми параметрами у меня пишет ошибку "Необходимо заполнить поле "firstname"". Измените на "firstname"        =>  "Сергей", у вас был лишний пробел в ключе

Comment: проставил curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); и удалил пробел у закрытия кавычек firstname - все заработало, огромное спасибо!